# Sharing code over a lot of files

Tags: discussion, code-length

I'm working on a multithreaded server and have a few questions regarding it, especially the best way of going around decoupling the server module (that manages the connections) from the application module (that does the actual work).  While my implementation works for simple cases I don't think it's up to the job for something substantial.

I want to share the code on CodeReview.  I know you're normally expected to post the code into the question itself for practical reasons (namely hosting the code on another site means the code isn't available for review if that site goes down), however the server's code spans a number of classes and interfaces of typically a hundred to a couple of hundred lines long.  I don't think people would want to read through all that.

How would you advise sharing code that's distributed across several files and of significant length for review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't think people would want to read through all that.

Then why do you want to post all of it?

The code you post should be your real code, but it doesn't have to be all of it. Post only the classes you want reviewed. Maybe don't include implementation of some interfaces. If you can't cleanly separate your code across class lines, omit some methods.

(BTW, if you're not able to separate your code like this, it might indicate that your code is too tightly coupled.)